# Missing conditional format option in card visual in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Previously, my Power BI file had the option to format the card value. But now it’s missing. I installed updated the Power BI version too. There isn't any option to format the value color conditionally in card visual.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug with an imminent fix. It should be fixed in version 2.109.782.0 according to the discussion on Power BI forums:

*[Conditional Formatting missing in September release](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Conditional-Formatting-missing-in-September-release/idi-p/2765703)*